# Hot Dog Stand static function issue

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

I need this program to create a new HotDogStand object that is able to track how many hot dogs are sold by each stand individually and all together, and I cannot figure out how to make my static method work to find the total number of hot dogs sold between all stands. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class HotDogStand
{
    public:
        HotDogStand(int id, int hds);
        void justSold();
        int getNumSold();
        int getID();
        int getTotalSold();
    private:
        int idNum;
        int hotDogsSold;
    static int totalSold;
};

HotDogStand::HotDogStand(int id, int hds)
{
    idNum = id;
    hotDogsSold = hds;
    return;
}

void HotDogStand::justSold()
{
    hotDogsSold++;
    return;
}

int HotDogStand::getNumSold()
{
    return hotDogsSold;
}

int HotDogStand::getID()
{
    return idNum;
}

int HotDogStand::getTotalSold()
{
    totalSold = 0;
    totalSold += hotDogsSold;
}

int main()
{
    HotDogStand s1(1, 0), s2(2, 0), s3(3, 0);

    s1.justSold();
    s2.justSold();
    s1.justSold();

    cout << "Stand " << s1.getID() << " sold " << s1.getNumSold() << "." << endl;
    cout << "Stand " << s2.getID() << " sold " << s2.getNumSold() << "." << endl;
    cout << "Stand " << s3.getID() << " sold " << s3.getNumSold() << "." << endl;
    cout << "Total sold = " << s1.getTotalSold() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    s3.justSold();
    s1.justSold();

    cout << "Stand " << s1.getID() << " sold " << s1.getNumSold() << "." << endl;
    cout << "Stand " << s2.getID() << " sold " << s2.getNumSold() << "." << endl;
    cout << "Stand " << s3.getID() << " sold " << s3.getNumSold() << "." << endl;
    cout << "Total sold = " << s1.getTotalSold() << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you want to tell how many `s1,s2,s3` are sold separately, you can't use static member in this case.

Comment: what are errors you are facing?

Comment: I'm not having an issue with the separate total, I just can't figure out how to find the combined total of all three hot dog stands. (It should be 3 the first run and 5 for the second.) @billz

Comment: It gives me an undefined reference to 'HotDogStand::totalSold' @HeenaGoyal

Comment: You've got several obvious problems. I hope you don't take this as rude, but I think you'd be best served reviewing your class notes (I'm presuming this is course work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally (outside of the class), you have to define the static variable:

```
int HotDogStand::totalSold = 0;
```

Change

```
void HotDogStand::justSold()
{
    hotDogsSold++;
    totalSold++;    // increment here
    return;
}
```

And

```
int HotDogStand::getTotalSold()
{
    return totalSold;   // just return value
}
```